# what is the meaning of writing a number near to write loop

Tags: python, while-loop

```
t=int(input())
while t:
    t-=1
    n,m=map(int,input().split())
    print((n-1)*(m-1))
```

`while t` here makes me confused , is it always true ? i have no idea to describe it.I have never seen this .Could you explain what is going on here with explaination , please ,thank you!

Comment: Every iteration, t decreases by 1 in `t-=1`. It will exit when it reaches 0.

Comment: t  depends on the user of your input. first if the user type a word it will cause error, secondly if he types numbers 0 is evaluated as false, any other int is evaluated as true, so it will keep evaluating true until t become 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`t` will be `True` unless it equals to 0 (which is logical `False` in Python).

In your case, if `t` is positive, it will be decreased by 1 and the while loop will stop after `t=0`.

But if the input will be negative number, the loop will run infinitely.

Answer (score 1):

`0` is `False` is a boolean context, any other number is `True`.

So here, the loop continues until `t` is reduced to `0`.

Answer (score 0):

In your case while accept a integer `t` as the condition. Where the loop iterates until t is 0.

```
while expression:
   statement(s)
```

The condition here may be any expression, and true is any non-zero value. The loop iterates while the condition is true.

Answer (score 0):

`while` loop works when the parameter it contains is true.
So in your example, it will evaluate the value of `t` this way: `bool(t)`. If it will be `False` then the loop will stop.